# Row wise percent difference from reference row by group data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data that looks like the following:

```
Seller              Name                        Price
ⒽomeⓄnline         Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 51.7
HomeOnline          Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 62.54
Amazon.com          Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 41.83
XpW                 Honeywell Safe Chest        41.37
XoXoGroupLLC        Honeywell Safe Chest        51.78
Toys Online         Honeywell Safe Chest        43.01
Tempus & Co.        Honeywell Safe Chest        52.7
stores123           Honeywell Safe Chest        51.21
ⒽomeⓄnline         Honeywell Safe Chest        43.88
HomeOnline          Honeywell Safe Chest        43.87
Great Brands Outlet Honeywell Safe Chest        64.95
Connect Buy         Honeywell Safe Chest        30.1
Amazon.com          Honeywell Safe Chest        24.6
```

I want to calculate the percent difference between each row and the row where Amazon.com is the seller by `Name`. So that the output looks like this with the 'etc...' meaning the row is populated down all the way:

```
    Seller              Name                        Price     Pct_Diff
    ⒽomeⓄnline         Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 51.7       .23
    HomeOnline          Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 62.54      .49
    Amazon.com          Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 41.83
    XpW                 Honeywell Safe Chest        41.37      .68    
    XoXoGroupLLC        Honeywell Safe Chest        51.78      1.0
    Toys Online         Honeywell Safe Chest        43.01      etc...
    Tempus & Co.        Honeywell Safe Chest        52.7
    stores123           Honeywell Safe Chest        51.21
    ⒽomeⓄnline         Honeywell Safe Chest        43.88
    HomeOnline          Honeywell Safe Chest        43.87
    Great Brands Outlet Honeywell Safe Chest        64.95
    Connect Buy         Honeywell Safe Chest        30.1
    Amazon.com          Honeywell Safe Chest        24.6
```

I think there's a good `data.table` solution for this. But I can't figure out how to compare each row that is does not have "Amazon.com" as the seller to the row that does have "Amazon.com" as the seller.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput` for your data example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
dt[, pct := (Price - Price[Seller=='Amazon.com'])/Price[Seller=='Amazon.com'], by = Name]
```

which gives:

> ```
>                  Seller                        Name Price       pct
>  1:         ⒽomeⓄnline Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 51.70 0.2359551
>  2:          HomeOnline Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 62.54 0.4950992
>  3:          Amazon.com Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 41.83 0.0000000
>  4:                 XpW        Honeywell Safe Chest 41.37 0.6817073
>  5:        XoXoGroupLLC        Honeywell Safe Chest 51.78 1.1048780
>  6:         Toys Online        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.01 0.7483740
>  7:        Tempus & Co.        Honeywell Safe Chest 52.70 1.1422764
>  8:           stores123        Honeywell Safe Chest 51.21 1.0817073
>  9:         ⒽomeⓄnline        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.88 0.7837398
> 10:          HomeOnline        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.87 0.7833333
> 11: Great Brands Outlet        Honeywell Safe Chest 64.95 1.6402439
> 12:         Connect Buy        Honeywell Safe Chest 30.10 0.2235772
> 13:          Amazon.com        Honeywell Safe Chest 24.60 0.0000000
> ```

The same logic implemented in `dplyr`:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(pct = (Price - Price[Seller=='Amazon.com'])/Price[Seller=='Amazon.com'])
```

---

Used data:

```
dt <- structure(list(Seller = c("ⒽomeⓄnline", "HomeOnline", "Amazon.com", "XpW", "XoXoGroupLLC", "Toys Online", "Tempus & Co.", "stores123", "ⒽomeⓄnline", "HomeOnline", "Great Brands Outlet", "Connect Buy", "Amazon.com"), 
                     Name = c("Harper Hand Truck and Dolly", "Harper Hand Truck and Dolly", "Harper Hand Truck and Dolly", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest"),
                     Price = c(51.7, 62.54, 41.83, 41.37, 51.78, 43.01, 52.7, 51.21, 43.88, 43.87, 64.95, 30.1, 24.6)),
                .Names = c("Seller", "Name", "Price"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution

```
libary(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Seller = c("ⒽomeⓄnline", "HomeOnline", "Amazon.com", "XpW", "XoXoGroupLLC", "Toys Online", "Tempus & Co.", "stores123", "ⒽomeⓄnline", "HomeOnline", "Great Brands Outlet", "Connect Buy", "Amazon.com"),
  Name = c("Harper Hand Truck and Dolly","Harper Hand Truck and Dolly","Harper Hand Truck and Dolly","Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest", "Honeywell Safe Chest"),
  Price = c(51.7, 62.54, 41.83, 41.37, 51.78, 43.01, 52.7, 51.21, 43.88, 43.87, 64.95, 30.1, 24.6)
)

df %>% 
  # Join each row with the "Amazon.com" price for this item
  left_join(df %>% filter(Seller == "Amazon.com"), by = "Name", suffix = c("", ".amazon")) %>%
  # Remove unused "Seller" column
  select(-Seller.amazon) %>%
  # Calculate percentage for each row, except for
  # "Amazon.com" rows, for which the percent difference is NA
  mutate(Pct_Diff = ifelse(Seller == "Amazon.com", NA, round((Price - Price.amazon) / Price.amazon, 2)))

#                      Seller                        Name Price Price.amazon Pct_Diff
# 1  <U+24BD>ome<U+24C4>nline Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 51.70        41.83     0.24
# 2                HomeOnline Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 62.54        41.83     0.50
# 3                Amazon.com Harper Hand Truck and Dolly 41.83        41.83       NA
# 4                       XpW        Honeywell Safe Chest 41.37        24.60     0.68
# 5              XoXoGroupLLC        Honeywell Safe Chest 51.78        24.60     1.10
# 6               Toys Online        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.01        24.60     0.75
# 7              Tempus & Co.        Honeywell Safe Chest 52.70        24.60     1.14
# 8                 stores123        Honeywell Safe Chest 51.21        24.60     1.08
# 9  <U+24BD>ome<U+24C4>nline        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.88        24.60     0.78
# 10               HomeOnline        Honeywell Safe Chest 43.87        24.60     0.78
# 11      Great Brands Outlet        Honeywell Safe Chest 64.95        24.60     1.64
# 12              Connect Buy        Honeywell Safe Chest 30.10        24.60     0.22
# 13               Amazon.com        Honeywell Safe Chest 24.60        24.60       NA
```